# I want to put an image before the appbar

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to put a container before the appbar

Answer (score 0):

To implement non-trivial views you should consider [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

Below some working solution:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          // Image
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            forceElevated: false,
            collapsedHeight: 100,
            expandedHeight: 100,
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://blog.depositphotos.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Soothing-nature-backgrounds-2-1024x684.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // AppBar
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            forceElevated: false,
            title: Text('Sliver App Bar'),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(child: Text('CLICK'), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          // Content
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                title: Text('Title $index'),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont want the photo to move when i scroll

Comment: is there any way to put a container before the app bar

Comment: If you use `Scaffold` no. But you may create your own behavour. I mean remove `appBar` prop and modify `body` widget for your needs placing image first and then draw your own appbar.

Comment: @thresh, I updated my answer. It looks I can achive some result. Please try and modify on your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add **`bottom`** in your **AppBar** widget and use **`PreferredSize`**:-

```
 bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(double.maxFinite, 45), // Set this size as per your requirement
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset("Any Image")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Fyi, this don't work. Topic starter wants to have image *before* appBar.

Comment: Then you have to create custom app bar